# Returning a value for an actual cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets: sheet1 and sheet2.

- In sheet2 I have a column "C" called addresses and in that column I have actual cell addresses such as $J$740, $H$756, etc, all referring to cell locations in Sheet1.
- In sheet1 in column "B" are names.

I would like to be able to return the names from sheet1 column "B" to column "G" of sheet2 that belong to the cell address from column "C" in sheet2.

Is there an Excel formula that will do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all I found the answer to my question - thanks again for your help

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!B$1,RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND("$",C2,2))-1,0)
```

Comment: Well, you found *an* answer. And not a very robust one at that. Why not save yourself some trouble and just use the built-in `INDIRECT`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is very the purpose of the `INDIRECT` function.

In cell G2, you can write:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet1!"&C2)
```

and copy this formula down column G.

This will take the text in cell C2, say `$J$740`, and append it to the text `sheet1!` to give `sheet1!$J$740`. The `INDIRECT` function then returns the value of the cell corresponding to that address (cell J740 on sheet1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this function returns the value of the address of the cell. What I am looking for is for it to return the corresponding name in column B of sheet1.